# How can I compare a string to data in a json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Something like this in my index.js:

```
if('and' == trueWords){
    console.log('Success!')
} else {
    console.log('Failure!')
}
```

And here is my json file:

```
{
  "and": 1
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need more details. How do you get the JSON file and what is `trueWords`?

Comment: Firstly, how do you import your json file in the code.. you should check that.. it could be via ajax. And then do the comparison. I feel your if statement is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you want to check if the JSON contains certain property??

if that is the case, we need first to understand a very basic thing about JS Objects:

**EVERYTHING IS AN ARRAY**

what that gives us is the ability to check if there is a certain property exists on our object.

achieving the requirements you've posted with the following.

```
if(!!trueWords['and']){
    console.log('Success!')
}else{
    console.log('Failure!')
}
```

**That if I understood what you're looking for correctly, otherwise please comment more details**

Comment: Thanks it worked! However I don't see the point in using '!!' when I tested it without and it still works. Could you provide a reason as to why you used it?

Comment: using !! for this, in javascript there something called a faulty object, for example if you try the following 
var x=0; or x={} or x="" or x=undefined...etc 
if(x){}else{}
it'll always hit the else
using !! to make sure it evaluates the logical condition for the object is being faulty or not.

you can remove it and it'll work fine, but for non-primitive data types you'll need it

Answer (score 1):

Morning you can use regex to check this.

First you need to import file like this:

```
///ES6 code
import json from "./jsonfile.json";
// before ES6
var json = require("./jsonfile.json");
```

And then something like this

```
var reg = new RegExp(/\s+/)
if(reg.test(json.and))
  console.log('just word characters');
else
  console.log('there another characters')
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must consume / read file with module fs from node module and make newdata and than write files, here

load module fs / filesystem

`let fs = requiire('fs')`

readfile

`let readdata = fs.readFileSync('./index.js', 'utf-8')`

here docs

[https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position][1]